# How to test for blank line with Java Scanner?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am expecting input with the scanner until there is nothing (i.e. when user enters a blank line). How do I achieve this?

I tried:

```
while (scanner.hasNext()) {
    // process input
}
```

But that will get me stuck in the loop

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Here's a way:

```
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
String line = null;
while(!(line = keyboard.nextLine()).isEmpty()) {
  String[] values = line.split("\\s+");
  System.out.print("entered: " + Arrays.toString(values) + "\n");
}
System.out.print("Bye!");
```

Comment: This has a side effect of getting the line already (eg. I'd need to split the line by spaces for example if I want to parse values separated by spaces). Is there a `hasNextLine()` type method where the "pointer" doesn't goto the next line?

Comment: @jiewmeng - when you call `scanner.hasNext()` you will need to still fetch the line to check whether it is empty and process it. Could you explain why Bart's answer would not work for you?

Comment: The problem with splitting the line is that it defeats the purpose of the `Scanner`, which is that it helps you do the tokenizing.

Answer (score 9):

From http://www.java-made-easy.com/java-scanner-help.html:

> Q: What happens if I scan a blank line with Java's Scanner?
>
> A: It depends. If you're using nextLine(), a blank line will be read
>   in as an empty String. This means that if you were to store the blank
>   line in a String variable, the variable would hold "". It will NOT
>   store " " or however many spaces were placed. If you're using next(),
>   then it will not read blank lines at all. They are completely skipped.

My guess is that `nextLine()` will still trigger on a blank line, since technically the Scanner will have the empty String `""`. So, you could check `if s.nextLine().equals("")`

Answer (score 9):

The problem with the suggestions to use `scanner.nextLine()` is that it actually returns the next line as a `String`.  That means that any text that is there gets consumed.  If you are interested in scanning the contents of that line… well, too bad!  You would have to parse the contents of the returned `String` yourself.

A better way would be to use

```
while (scanner.findInLine("(?=\\S)") != null) {
    // Process the line here…
    …

    // After processing this line, advance to the next line (unless at EOF)
    if (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        scanner.nextLine();
    } else {
        break;
    }
}
```

Since `(?=\S)` is a zero-width lookahead assertion, it will never consume any input.  If it finds any non-whitespace text in the current line, it will execute the loop body.

You could omit the `else break;` if you are certain that the loop body will have consumed all non-whitespace text in that line already.

Comment: What does "consumed" mean in this context?

Comment: @Jason210 "Consumed" means that if you ask the scanner for the next item, it will give you something from the next line rather than the current line, because the scanner's state has already moved past the line break.

Comment: This is exactly what I need for console input. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
Scanner key = new Scanner(new File("data.txt"));
String data = "";

while(key.hasNextLine()){
    String nextLine = key.nextLine();

    data += nextLine.equals("") ? "\n" :nextLine;

}
System.out.println(data);
```

Answer (score -1):

AlexFZ is right, `scanner.hasNext()` will always be true and loop doesn't end, because there is always string input even though it is empty "".

I had a same problem and i solved it like this:

```
do{
    // process input

    }while(line.length()!=0);
```

I think `do-while` will fit here better becasue you have to evaluate input after user has entered it.