# System.out.println does not work

Tags: java

I am beginner in learning java programming. Basically, I can't make the last bit of my code to work. Before I show you my code, I think it is a good idea to show how the result should be. The result of the program should be:

```
Please Enter either S(supply) or R(replenish) followed by ID and quantity.
R     p122.   10
New Stock-level for p122(Chain) is 58
S.    p124.   20
New Stock-level for p125(Pedal) is 18
S.    p905.   20
No part found with ID p905
.....// enter empty string to terminate
//Show final stock levels of all Parts
```

Although, I did be able to perform the main calculation and everything, I cannot print out the final stock levels of all Parts. I really don't understand why.
Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestPart {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Array of 5 Part objects
    // Part[] part = new Part[5];
    Part[] part = new Part[5];
    part[0] = new Part("p122", "Chain", 48, 12.5);
    part[1] = new Part("p123", "Chain Guard", 73, 22.0);
    part[2] = new Part("p124", "Crank", 400, 11.5);
    part[3] = new Part("p125", "Pedal", 3, 6.5);
    part[4] = new Part("p126", "Handlebar", 123, 9.50);

    ///////// Test Class 2 ////////
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please Enter either S (supply) or R (replenish) followed by ID and quantity.");
    while (scanner.hasNext()) {

        String sOrR = scanner.next();
        String inputId = scanner.next();
        int amount = scanner.nextInt();

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            String id = part[i].getID();
            // Find ID in array
            if (id.equals(inputId)) {
                // S or R
                if (sOrR.equals("R")) {
                    part[i].replenish(amount);
                } else {

                    part[i].supply(amount);

                }
                System.out.println("New Stock-level for " + part[i].getID() + "(" + part[i].getName() + ") is "
                        + part[i].getStockLevel());
            }

        }
        if ((inputId.equals(part[0].getID()) == false) && (inputId.equals(part[1].getID()) == false)
                && (inputId.equals(part[2].getID()) == false) && (inputId.equals(part[3].getID()) == false)
                && (inputId.equals(part[4].getID()) == false)) {
            System.out.println("No part found with ID " + inputId);
        }

    }
    scanner.close();

    System.out.println("Final stock level for all the parts: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        System.out.println("Final Stock-level for " + part[i].getID() + "(" + part[i].getName() + ") is "
                + part[i].getStockLevel());
    }
}
}
```

My program executes perfectly the calculating part. However it doesn't display final stocklevels.

```
 Please Enter either S(supply) or R(replenish) followed by ID and quantity.
    R     p122.   10
    New Stock-level for p122(Chain) is 58
    S.    p124.   20
    New Stock-level for p125(Pedal) is 18
    S.    p905.   20
    No part found with ID p905
```

Comment: Why dont you debug your code?

Comment: the program does calculating and print out for example: Please Enter either S(supply) or R(replenish) followed by ID and quantity.
R     p122.   10
New Stock-level for p122(Chain) is 58
S.    p124.   20
New Stock-level for p125(Pedal) is 18
S.    p905.   20
No part found with ID p905

Comment: but it does not display the final stock levels...

Comment: Can you show us what it does print out?

Comment: @TamLam so what does the code in `Part` do i.e. the methods `supply` and `replenish`?  If "//Show final stock levels of all Parts" shows the original stock levels then you need to implement stuff on Part..

Comment: _Why doesn't last bit my code works?_ is not a useful title to anyone but yourself. Please edit it to reflect the actual issue.

Comment: @earncam yes, I have done it. Check the last bit of codes.

Comment: How do you perform end of the loop? It won't exit when you enter empty string.

Answer (score 0):

Your abort condition (namely `scanner.hasNext()`) won't exit the `while` loop whenever the user enters an empty string. I don't know if you already noticed but whenever the user only hits the return key, nothing happens because `Scanner.next` does not trigger on return only. Though be aware that it stores your input. That means once you enter a "valid" input (such as `abc`), the `Scanner` will give you everything the user just entered before that valid input. Just a small example to demonstrate what I mean:

```java
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
while(scanner.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println("\"" + scanner.next() + "\"");
}
scanner.close();
System.out.println("finished");
```

So, if you want to abort your program after the user entered an empty line, this is not possible with `java.util.Scanner.hasNext`. I recommend you add another character to your "S or R" option that allows the user to exit the program like this:

```java
if(sOrR.equals("E")) break;
```

You should place this directly behind `String sOrR = scanner.next();`.

Comment: Thank you, you actually answered my question. However, I do not allow to add another argument in order to terminate the while loop. I can only use empty string...

Comment: @TamLam Then I'll mark your answer as a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7320315/how-to-test-for-blank-line-with-java-scanner