# Java: Making a program keep prompting for user input when they enter nothing

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, input, while-loop

I'm writing a program that asks for user input and keeps prompting the user for valid input if any of a few conditions aren't met. One such condition is that the input can't be an empty string. (i.e. the user typing nothing and just pressing Enter). How can I test for this? This is the code I have so far:
(Note: the method isDateAcceptable isn't really relevant here because I want it to say "Number not acceptable." then re-prompt if the user enters "").
EDIT: I should add that with the current code, when a user enters an empty string the cursor just moves to the next line without ending the program.

```
public static String getNumOrDate(Scanner console){
    System.out.print("Enter a number or a date mm/dd/yyyy (-1 to exit):");
    String input = console.next();
    while(!input.equals("-1")) {
        if(input.isEmpty()){
            System.out.println("Number not acceptable.");
            getNumOrDate(console);
        }
        if (input.contains("/")) {
            while (!isDateAcceptable(input)) {
                System.out.println("Date not acceptable.");
                getNumOrDate(console);
            }
        } else if (canBeParsed(input)) {
            while (!isNumberAcceptable(input)) {
                System.out.println("Number not acceptable.");
                getNumOrDate(console);
            }
        }

    }
    System.out.println(isNumberAcceptable(input));
    return input;
}

public static boolean canBeParsed(String input){
    boolean parsable = true;
    try{
        Integer.parseInt(input);
    }catch(NumberFormatException e){
        parsable = false;
    }
    return parsable;
}
public static boolean isNumberAcceptable (String s){
    boolean isAcceptable = true;
    int numDigits = s.length();
    if(s.isEmpty()&& s == null){
        isAcceptable = false;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < numDigits; i++){
        if(!Character.isDigit(s.charAt(i))){
            isAcceptable = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    if(isAcceptable){
        int number = Integer.parseInt(s);
        if((number < 1 && number != -1) || number > MAX_NUMBER){
            isAcceptable = false;
        }
    }
    return isAcceptable;
}
```

Comment: Strings have an `isEmpty` method. Is that not working?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to test for blank line with Java Scanner?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7320315/how-to-test-for-blank-line-with-java-scanner)

Comment: I'd be inclined to use `nextLine()` instead of `next()` for this kind of thing.  You're trying to get input a line at a time, not a word at a time.

Answer (score 0):

I advise you to create a new JFrame window and drag an input field and a button into it.Select the button and add an event on it.Then you can ge the string with the method getText().and check if it is "" or not.If your requirement is met than you can close the Jframe if not it will still remain open.

Comment: Seriously?  OP is struggling to learn how console input works, and your advice is to have him/her do something that's significantly more complicated instead?