# In IntelliJ IDEA, while taking input in an array from console, character of enter key is accepted as an element

Tags: java, arrays, input

I was seeing an example of linear search in an array in Java, and I wrote this code:

```
import java.util.*;
public class LinearSearch
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter no. of members: ");
        int l=sc.nextInt();
        String[] list=new String[l];
        System.out.println("Enter the members: ");
        for(int i=0;i<l;i++)
            list[i]=sc.nextLine();
        System.out.print("\nEnter the member you want to search for: ");
        String ts=sc.nextLine();
        for(int i=0;i<l;i++)
        {
            if(list[i].equalsIgnoreCase(ts))
            {
                System.out.println("The member is at index " + i);
                break;
            }
            if(i==l-1)
                System.out.println("There is no such member");
        }
    }
}
```

But while running this code, due to the `System.out.println()` at the 10th line, the carriage return (of the `println()` ) is taken as the element at index 0. Further, as I enter more elements, after each element I need to press Enter key to start the next iteration, but with that, the carriage return of the Enter key is taken as input too. This is the output:

```
Enter no. of members: 5
Enter the members: 
a
b
c

Enter the member you want to search for: e
There is no such member
```

I did the following to prevent it:

```
System.out.println("Enter the members: ");
int j=0;
String in="";
while(list[l-1]==null)
{
    in=sc.nextLine();
    if(in.equals(String.valueOf((char)10))) //10 being the ASCII code of carriage return
        continue;
    else
    {
        list[j] = in;
        j++;
    }
}
```

But this doesn't work, it still takes carriage return as an element. Is there any way to fix this issue ?

Comment: see [Scanner is skipping nextLine() after using next() or nextFoo()?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13102045/16320675)

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7320315/how-to-test-for-blank-line-with-java-scanner
whitespace

Comment: So how can I read the string wihtout readng the carriage return ? Putting a Scanner.nextLine() after it will work ?

Comment: As told by @Yuvaraj R, I tested it in BlueJ and put a Scanner.nextLine() after Scanner.nextInt() and it works. Thank you very much. So will this bug in IntelliJ be fixed in next version ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to skip line after nextInt() call as in the answer mentioned by @user16320675 in the comment

But, there is another bug in Intellij IDEA console, refer [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72340420/5044508) which kind of skips alternative nextLine() input. Hence, your call ends even when you just enter 3 values in this case but your array size is 5.

Refer

[image: IDEA output]

Your program is still correct. Just test your code in other terminal instead of IDEA console

[image: Terminal Output]

Comment: I tested it in BlueJ. The code works correctly and by putting a Scanner.nextLine() after the Scanner.nextInt() makes it work perfectly. It really works now. Thank you very much.

Comment: @ShrieshKumar great! and yes it is fixed already and will be available in next version as mentioned in the tracker. Please accept the answer